# pandas read_html: how to read columns that contain &nbsp;?

Tags: html, pandas

I am trying to read a html-table with python that looks like this:

```
+------------+---------+
|    ID      | Value   |
+------------+---------+
| 1          | 12 098  |
| 2          |     20  |
| 3          | 123 456 |
+------------+---------+
```

In html-code the elements look like this:

`<span> 123&nbsp;456</span>`

Pandas reads this as object but I need it to be numeric. I tried:

```
df_tables=pd.read_html(table_html,header=0,thousands='&nbsp;')
```

and

```
 df_tables=pd.read_html(table_html,header=0,thousands=' ')
```

But the column is always 'object'.

I tried casting to float:

`df_table['Value']=df_table['Value'].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')`

But that just deleted the values in the columns where there was a blank space.

Subsequently I tried to strip the space from the column before applying to numeric:

`df_table=df_table['Value'].map(lambda x: x.strip(' '))`

But that doesn't seem to have any effect. I'd prefer to fix this while reading the html but I am happy to accept any solution that gives me a numeric column at this point.

**Update:**

I can not remove `&nbsp;` from the source html because there are other columns that contain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
df_table['Value'] = df_table['Value'].str.replace('\D', '').astype(int)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you very much! Just fyi, it also works without the astype(str): `df_table['Value'] = df_table['Value'].str.replace('\D', '').astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this

```
import pandas as pd

html_string = """
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>value</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1&nbsp;230</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>100</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>220</td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
"""

html_string = html_string.replace("&nbsp;","")

df_table = pd.read_html(html_string)
dfs = df_table[0]

for (index, row) in dfs.iterrows():
    print(float(row[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question: I can't remove the nbsp from the html because there are other columns in that table that contain text. I didn't mention this before because I wanted the question to be short. My bad.